# How can I calculate the proportion of influence 2 factors have on a continuous variable?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, variance

I have a dependent continuos, but not normal variable y and want to know how much of the variance of y is explained by x_1 and x_2. Both x variables are nominal. The Levene test y~x_1+x_2 led to the result of homogenous variances.
What kind of analysis can i use to answer that question?